# Pagination not working on custom Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been working on creating a custom loop and setting how many posts per page. I needed to make this loop separate to the blog posts per page - hence the custom loop.

Now the loop does work, however I noticed it is conflicting with the pagniation... pagination is showing but pages are not changing when you click 'next'.

Here is my loop:

```
<?php 
     $args = array('posts_per_page'=>12, 'post_type' =>'office'); 
     $category_posts = new WP_Query($args); 

    if($category_posts->have_posts()) :  
    while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
    $category_posts->the_post();
?>

    <div class="office-item-wrapper">

        <div class="office-item">

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


            </article>

        </div>

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <article>
        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing to display.', 'html5blank' ); ?></h2>
    </article><!--/ Article -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to help me solve this issue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WP, the pagination is sent by a `GET` variable under `page`, just add it to the query args:

```
$page = get_query_var('paged');
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>12, 'post_type' =>'office', 'paged'=>$page);
```

I recommend you to use `get_query_var('paged')` because if it's empty it will be send you to the first page.

**Note:** *In some themes, the page number is sent in the `page` key, so try with `page` or `paged`.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would I implement this in the above code?

Comment: You're welcome. Then select my answer as the answer. Just copy and paste my code and replace your $args line